# cannot be driven by primitives or continuous assignment

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I got

> reg OUT; cannot be driven by primitives or continuous assignment.

error.

The Counter module is:

```
module Counter(
    input             clk,
    input             clear,
    input             load,
    input             up_down, // UP/~DOWN
    input[3:0]        IN,
    input             count,
    output reg[3:0]   OUT
    );
    always @(posedge clk, negedge clear)
    if (~clear) OUT <= 4'b0000;
    else if(load) OUT <= IN;
    else if(count)
    begin
       if(up_down) OUT <= OUT + 1'b1;
       else OUT <= OUT - 1'b1;
    end
    else OUT <= OUT;
endmodule
```

And the testbench is:

```
module test;
   .
   .
   .
   reg [3:0] IN;
   reg [3:0] OUT;

   Counter c1(clk, clear, load, up_down, IN, count, OUT);
endmodule
```

The error is in the `Counter c1(clk, clear, load, up_down, IN, count, OUT);` line.

Comment: This code is now legal in SystemVerilog, but was not in Verilog.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the `test` module has this declaration:

```
reg [3:0] OUT;
```

A `reg` should not be connected to a module `output`.

Change `reg` to `wire` in `test`, then make sure no other signal drives the `OUT` net in `test`:

```
wire [3:0] OUT;
```